# Latex is automatically making 1 word italic and I can't find a way to make it normal. How can I fix this?

Tags: bold, text

[image: This is my source code]

[image: and this is the output]

I want the word seconds to be in bold and not italics like the rest and I can't figure out why it's different. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\epsilon` is a math mode command you must have had an error at that point, The pdf is not intended to be used after _any_ error.

Comment: The command `\epsilon` is only valid in math mode, LaTeX is attempting to help by starting math mode for you but then it never leaves math mode. Also I think what you actually want is `\in`.

Comment: `$t \in [0,5]$` (I think you mean `\in` not `\epsilion` ?

Comment: Note that in this case it was easy enough to spot by eye but in general it is hard to debug an image, it is better to provide the example as a small complete document as text so people can debug it.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you render so much of the material in **bold**?

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `t \epsilon [0,5]` with `$t \in [0,5]$`. I.e., two changes are needed:

- use inline math mode for math material, and
- change `\epsilon` to `\in`.

A full MWE -- note that I would *not* render the paragraph in **bold** and that I would use the machinery of the `siunitx` package to typeset numbers and their associated scientific units. (If you insist on using **bold** for the text part, you should also make an effort to render the math part in bold.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\SI' macro

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}  % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{2}

\subsection{}

Compute the complete solution to the ordinary differential 
equation with input $x(t)=0$ assuming the circuit elements 
are $R=\SI{0.5}{\ohm}$, $L=\SI{0.1}{H}$, $C=0$ and initial
conditions $y(0)=1$ and $dy(t)\,dt\mid t=0$. Use MATLAB to
plot your solution for time interval $t\in[0,5]$ seconds.

\end{document}
```